# Alertdialog does not show view properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view, android-alertdialog

I want to create an AlertDialog to check if the two passwords match.The problem is that when I inflate the Views from layout,the dialog doesn't appear and so does the the OK and Cancel buttons Only the edittext are shown and that too in the Mainactivity.This is the code I used so far.Could someone help me out with this

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case MY_PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID:
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root));
        final EditText password1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.EditText_Pwd1);
        final EditText password2 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.EditText_Pwd2);
        final TextView error = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.TextView_PwdProblem);            


            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Enter Password");
            builder.setView(layout);
            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                      finish();
                   }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      String strPassword1 = password1.getText().toString();
                      String strPassword2 = password2.getText().toString();
                      if (strPassword1.equals(strPassword2)) {
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Matching passwords="+strPassword2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }

                   }
                });
                AlertDialog passwordDialog = builder.create();
                return passwordDialog;
        }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You are using custom dialog. Then you don't use the default `AlertDialog.setPositiveButton`. You can use only your customview button only try this,

```
 private Dialog mForgetPasswordDialog; 
 mForgetPasswordDialog = new Dialog(Signin.this);
    mForgetPasswordDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mForgetPasswordDialog.setContentView(R.layout.forget_password);
    mForgetPasswordDialog.setCancelable(true);
    edtGetmailId = (EditText) mForgetPasswordDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.edtGetEmailId);
    TextView btnOk = (TextView) mForgetPasswordDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        // do your stuff
        }
    });

    TextView btnCancel = (TextView) mForgetPasswordDialog
            .findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mForgetPasswordDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    mForgetPasswordDialog.show();
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work...could you please edit my code so i can see if I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Just copy and paste this code use your layout and your widgets

Comment: it says "The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){});